# Circular queue implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, circular-list

I've implemented a simple thread-safe circular queue. I'm looking for code review, optimizations and best practices.

```
public class CircularQueue {
    int[] queue; 
    int front;
    int rear; 
    int currentSize;
    int size;

    public CircularQueue(int size) { 
        this.queue = new int[size];
        this.front = 0;
        this.rear = 0;
        this.size = size;
        this.currentSize = 0;
    }

    public synchronized boolean add(int x) {

        if (currentSize == size) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The queue is full: front size: " + rear);
        }

        queue[rear++] = x;
        rear = (rear + 1) % size;
        currentSize++;

        return true;
    }

    public synchronized int peek() {
        if (front == rear) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The queue is empty");
        }
        return queue[front];
    }

    public synchronized int poll() {
        if (front > rear) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The queue is empty");
        }
        currentSize--;
        return queue[front++];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by others, you have some bugs.

- `add` increments `rear` twice.
- `poll` should wrap `front`.
- `poll` and `peek` use different emptiness tests. Here's where `isEmpty` and `isFull` would come in handy.
- And neither test is correct. When `front` and `rear` are equal (once you wrap the former), the queue is either empty or full. You can compare `currentSize` to `size` instead.

Answer (score 9):

## Explicit visibility

I don't like relying on standard visibility; explicit declaring takes away all doubts. Instead have this:

```
private int[] queue; 
private int front;
private int rear; 
private int currentSize;
private int size;
```

## Implicit this

Contrary to the above having explicit `this` is unneeded and takes away from the readability. You should only use it when there is ambiguity with a parameter name. This results in this:

```
queue = new int[size];
front = 0;
rear = 0;
this.size = size;
currentSize = 0;
```

## Naming

What is `currentSize` and how does it differ from `size`? At first glance I would think they're the same. Some alternative names

*size*:

- `size`
- `maxSize`

*currentSize*:

- `index`
- `offset`

## Iterator

If you want your class to be able to be used in a `foreach` loop, you could implement `Iterator<T>`.

## Generics

Your datastructure is not generic so you're losing out on a lot of possibilities.

## Kaput

Your code isn't working as it is. I'm not entirely sure why (it's 3:30 AM so I'm not going to debug it deeply anymore) but I followed a hunch and this small example demonstrates it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CircularQueue cq = new CircularQueue(3);
    cq.add(5);
    cq.add(10);
    System.out.println(cq.poll());
    cq.add(15);
    System.out.println(cq.poll());
}
```

You'll notice that the last call to `poll()` will throw you your self defined exception (aka `front > rear` evaluates to `true`).

Comment: Careful with this! `size = size` will make you sad.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: aha, thanks for pointing it out. I saw it when I read it but forgot about it when I wrote it.

Comment: I figured as much since you specified precisely when `this` was required in the preceding paragraph. :)

Answer (score 7):

It's cheating, but: if you are going to be looking at circular queues, you should really review the implementation of [Disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor).

Reviewing this implementation:

There's no particularly good reason to restrict it to ints, is there?  `CircularQueue<T>` isn't much more work.

It's likely a cleaner design to treat the `Queue` as being backed by an infinite array, rather than wrapping your pointers over and over again.  So front and rear should tell you which item in the queue history that they point at, and reserve the modulus function for accessing the array itself.  This gives you some nice invariants to check, like rear >= front.

I definitely get tangled by the variable names.  `insertCursor` and `retrieveCursor` might be clearer.  Or `writeTo` and `readFrom`.

Why aren't you implementing `java.util.Queue<T>`? (Answered by rolfl - because that interface brings too much baggage along with it.  It might still be a good idea to support offer(E), though.)

Throwing new exceptions each time you hit a problem condition can get expensive.  `java.util.Queue.add()` does it, so I suppose you've got some prior art in your defense, but if you aren't going to implement that interface, then perhaps you can more cleanly support congestion control.

Because every method is synchronized here, lock contention may get to be a problem when you start using this from multiple threads.

There doesn't seem to be a need for `currentSize`, since you can always compute it from front and back.

Do you really intend to expose these member variables to other classes in your package?  They should probably be private.  And the array should likely be final as well.

Comment: Implementing Queue also means implementing Collection, and that probably means, for pragmatic reasons, extending abstractConnection, which is probably not reinventing-the-wheel enough.... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I'm puzzled by this inconsistency in the way an empty queue is detected:

```
public synchronized int peek() {
    if (front == rear) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The queue is empty");
    }
    …
}

public synchronized int poll() {
    if (front > rear) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The queue is empty");
    }
    …
}
```

I believe `peek()` has it right, and `poll()` is wrong.

For that matter, why not check for `currentSize == 0`?  That would be the clearest way.

Comment: +1 checking with `currentSize` would also be consistent with the "queue is full" check.

Answer (score 4):

Some random notes:

- I'd rename `add` and `poll` to `push` and `pull`.
- `front` shall be wrapped around when it reaches `size`, just like `rear`. I hope it is just a typo.
- I don't see the reason for `peek` and `poll` to test different conditions. As coded, `poll` will return garbage if called before the first `add`.
- All methods should have blocking counterparts.

Comment: I am not convinced here. It is a Queue, not a Stack. Push is a bad term for a queue. Also that makes even less like the standard collections.